DOCKER, SPRING, MYSQL ENV error when use docker
I have problem when I use docker compose and connection string i assign in ENV not recognize in spring application.yml
this is my docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 23012003aA@
      MYSQL_DATABASE: checklist
    restart: always
  
  spring:
    build:
      context: ./back_end
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      - BE_PORT=9292
      - DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/checklist
      - DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123456789aA@
    ports:
      - "9292:9292"

this is my applicatiom.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/checklist?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: ${DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB

why when I run it not recognize my connection string.
I try to paste connection string but it not work.
it run error about hibernate.

For Spring to recognize the environment variables, the variable name needs to exactly match the Spring property name – to override spring.datasource.url you need to set SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL.  Also see Networking in Compose for more information about connecting between containers: you're trying to tell your Spring application to connect to localhost, its own container, and not the database container.

You seems like not clearly  about that how to associate spring applicatio with docker  .
The reason you failed is that  while both application and  database might in same docker-compose , but they are in indenpent docker container , it means if you indicate the resouce url as localhost , it would request the application container itself not databasereousce container.
Fail Reason
The resource you define in docker should build in same network ,besides this put resouce and application all of them in same network , you can achieve this by define network like following code snippet Docker-compose. after above step , we should inject the resource variables into spring application.yaml
Above operation Step By Step like following:

define network in docker-compose,
checkout the reource address
inject the database env variables to application
checkout spring application.yaml read the resouce from env

application.yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  multipart:
    max-file-size: 10MB
    max-request-size: 10MB


Docker-compose
version: '3'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 23012003aA@
      MYSQL_DATABASE: checklist
    restart: always
    networks:
      - my_network
  
  spring:
    build:
      context: ./back_end
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      - BE_PORT=9292
      - DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/checklist?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123456789aA@
    ports:
      - "9292:9292"
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge




Compose automatically creates a network named default and attaches containers to it.  For most applications you do not need any networks: blocks in your Compose file.

@David Maze  , You mean that  it is uncessary to build a new network?  just use container name as host for request  each other  ?

Yes.  If you change your example to change the name my_network to default, that is exactly what Compose provides if you don't declare networks: at all.  Also see Networking in Compose in the Docker documentation.

 ERROR : Failed 
to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
spring-1    | CheckList_project  o.s.boot.SpringApplication                         reportFailure 2024-04-15 Mon 15:34:45 [      ] ERROR : Application run failed
spring-1    | 
spring-1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
spring-1    |   ... 31 common frames omitted
spring-1    | 
spring-1    | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring-1    | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
spring-1    | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring-1    | [INFO] Total time:  6.347 s
spring-1    | [INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-15T15:34:45Z
spring-1    | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring-1    | [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.3:run (default-cli) on project checklistproject_server: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
spring-1    | [ERROR]
spring-1    | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
spring-1    | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
spring-1    | [ERROR]
spring-1    | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
spring-1    | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

after I change follow us but my spring application return this error for me.
this is my application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/checklist?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:root}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:123@}
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect


my docker compose for spring and mysql
 mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 23012003aA@
      MYSQL_DATABASE: checklist
    restart: always
    networks:
      - checklist-network
  spring:
    build:
      context: ./back_end
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
      - keycloak
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=9292
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3307/checklist?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123@
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT=INFO
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK=ERROR
    ports:
      - "9292:9292"
    networks:
      - checklist-network


